# Dynamic background color for qTip2

Tags: javascript, jquery, qtip2

Does anyone know if it's possible to control the background color of qTip2 in the script? I'm able to set the message dynamically but I'm having trouble changing the background color. I have a series of different colored DIVs and I need the tool tip to change color depending on the background color of the DIV. With my javascript I'm able to get the background color of the DIVs but I just can't set the background color in qTip2.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(".tooltip").each(function(){
        $toolTip = $(this).data('title');
        var bgColor = $(this).css('backgroundColor');
        hexc(bgColor);
        function hexc(colorval) {
            var parts = colorval.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/);
            delete(parts[0]);
            for (var i = 1; i <= 3; ++i) {
                parts[i] = parseInt(parts[i]).toString(16);
                if (parts[i].length == 1) parts[i] = '0' + parts[i];
            }
            color = '#' + parts.join('');
            $bgColor = color;
        }

        $('.tool-tip').css('backgroundColor', $bgColor)

        $(this).qtip({
            content: {
                text: $toolTip
            },
            position: {
                my: 'bottom right',
                at: 'top right',
                target: 'mouse'
            },
            style: {
                classes: 'tool-tip',
                tip: {
                    height: 15  
                }
            }
        })
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

See [QTip2 dynamic show/hide events and slideDown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19456887/qtip2-dynamic-show-hide-events-and-slidedown/19466499#19466499) for how to change style classes dynamically. You should then be able to adjust the classes to match your divs.

Yes, I know this question was asked long ago, but hopefully it helps someone else.

The link provides this information:

There are at least three ways to set the Qtip options dynamically.

Set variables outside the qtip properties and use those
Use a Callback function, if available
Use an events function
I'm sure there are other ways to accomplish this, but the code below works for all the situations I needed, and demonstrates all three methods. I needed to use at least two, as the fadeIn method would not let me just use a variable. Nor could I just call the fadeIn method only if intFade was undefined.

So, hopefully this answer helps someone else.

```
function setupQtips()
{
  $("*[qtipiddiv]").each
  (
      function ()
      {
          //Title
          var elmTarget = $(this);
          var strTitle = elmTarget.attr('qtiptitle');
          if (strTitle == undefined)
          {
              strTitle = false;
          }

          //Title Button
          var binTitleButton = elmTarget.attr('qtipbutton');
          if (binTitleButton == undefined)
          {
              binTitleButton = false;
          }

          //Show
          var strShow = elmTarget.attr('qtipshow');
          if (strShow == undefined)
          {
              strShow = 'click';
          }

          if (strShow == 'false')
          {
              strShow = false;
          }

          //Hide
          var strHide = elmTarget.attr('qtiphide');
          if (strHide == undefined)
          {
              strHide = 'unfocus';
          }

          if (strHide == 'false')
          {
              strHide = false;
          }

          //Modal
          var binModal = elmTarget.attr('qtipmodal');
          var binBlur = false;
          if (binModal == undefined)
          {
              binModal = false;
          }
          else if (strHide == 'unfocus')
          {
              binBlur = true;
          }

          //Tip Height / width
          var intTipWidth = elmTarget.attr('qtiptipwidth');
          if (intTipWidth == undefined)
          {
              intTipWidth = 6;
          }

          var intTipHeight = elmTarget.attr('qtiptipheight');
          if (intTipHeight == undefined)
          {
              intTipHeight = 6;
          }

          //Style
          var strStyle = elmTarget.attr('qtipstyle');
          if (strStyle == undefined)
          {
              strStyle = '';
          }

          //____________________________________________________
          //Set qtip
          $(this).qtip
          (
              {
                  overwrite: false,
                  content:
                  {
                      text: function (event, api)
                      {
                          var strId = $(this).attr('qtipiddiv');
                          return ($('#' + strId));
                      },

                      title:
                      {
                          text: strTitle,

                          button: binTitleButton
                      }
                  },

                  show: 
                  {
                      event: strShow,

                      effect: function (offset)
                      {
                          var strFade = offset.target.attr('qtipfade');
                          if (strFade == undefined)
                          {
                              $(this).fadeIn(0);
                          }
                          else
                          {
                              var intFade = parseInt(strFade);
                              $(this).fadeIn(intFade);
                          }
                      },

                      solo: true,
                      modal:
                      {
                          on: binModal,
                          blur: binBlur
                      }
                  },  

                  hide:
                  {
                      event: strHide
                  },

                  position:
                  {
                      viewport: $(window),

                      adjust:
                      {
                          screen: true
                      }
                  },

                  style: 
                  {
                      classes: 'qtip-rounded qtip-shadow ' + strStyle,
                      tip:
                      {
                          width: intTipWidth,
                          height: intTipHeight
                      }
                  },

                  events:
                  {
                      show: function (event, api)
                      {
                          //Position
                          var elmTarget = $(api.elements.target[0]);
                          var strPositionMy = elmTarget.attr('qtippositionmy');
                          if (strPositionMy != undefined)
                          {
                              elmTarget.qtip('option', 'position.my', strPositionMy);
                          }

                          var strPositionAt = elmTarget.attr('qtippositionat');
                          if (strPositionAt != undefined)
                          {
                              elmTarget.qtip('option', 'position.at', strPositionAt);
                          }

                          //Height / width
                          var strWidth = elmTarget.attr('qtipwidth');
                          if (strWidth != undefined)
                          {
                              elmTarget.qtip('option', 'style.width', strWidth);
                          }

                          var strHeight = elmTarget.attr('qtipheight');
                          if (strHeight != undefined)
                          {
                              elmTarget.qtip('option', 'style.height', strHeight);
                          }
                      }
                  }
              }
          )
      }
  );

  return;
```

}

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Comment: Thanks kleopatra. Edited to include the relevant code.